# get state before currentstate in flex

Tags: apache-flex, states

I have five states in flex and change between them randomly.

How to get information about previous state (the active state before `currentState`) in flex?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6690063/398606)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener to the state changing event of your object and save the current state to a variable.

This could look like the following:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private var previousState : String;

        protected function onCreationComplete($event : FlexEvent) : void
        {
                    yourObject.addEventListener(StateChangeEvent.CURRENT_STATE_CHANGING,
                             onChangingState);
        }


        protected function onChangingState($event : StateChangeEvent) : void
        {
                    previousState = $event.oldState;
        }
```

Comment: this trik below can solve too
....
private var oldState:String;
....
<s:states>
  <s:State name="State1" exitState="oldState='State1'"/>
  <s:State name="imporState" exitState="oldState='imporState'"/>
  <s:State name="mapping2" exitState="oldState='mapping2'"/>
  <s:State name="berhasil_import" exitState="oldState='berhasil_import'"/>
  <s:State name="gagalImport" exitState="oldState='gagalImport'"/>
</s:states>